# Freeform only sends notifications with default template

Tags: solspace-freeform, notification

I'm using Freeform 4.1.3 (free) and I can only get it to send notifications when I use the default notification template.

I've tried declaring the template using both the module's settings and the template tags that override those. Neither worked. I've also tried stripping down my form to just the [example contact form](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#simple_contact_form). Still no-go. I can indeed send emails through EE's Communicate screen.

Ideas?

Comment: Mike, I've been getting the exact same behavior with 4.1.3 on EE 2.5.5. I've tried 4.1.5 but there's a fingerprint error that I've noted in another thread (http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20927/freeform-4-1-5-fingerprint-php-error)

Comment: Mike, I've been able to get the user notification template to be set, but the admin notification template does not work and only will use the default template. Did you get this working?

Comment: Ok, so I'm an idiot, and updating here to make sure you all know. I was using recipients, and never set a recipient template, assuming it would use the admin notification. D'oh.