# Freeform 4.1.5 fingerprint PHP error

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm running Freeform 4.1.3 on an EE 2.5.5 site. It is an MSM site.

I've been encountering the same issue mentioned here: [Freeform only sends notifications with default template](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/18882/freeform-only-sends-notifications-with-default-template)

I tried upgrading to the latest (4.1.5) and I encounter the following errors:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: fingerprint
Filename: addon_builder/addon_builder.php
Line Number: 4259
```

http://d.pr/i/inTS

In doing some debugging this appears to be related to some

I don't have a copy of 4.1.4 to test with to see if the same issue is happening with 4.1.4. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regression bug for EE 2.5.x and we are working on another release that will fix it.

If you want to patch it yourself in the mean time, replace the get_session_id function in:

```
./system/expressionengine/third_party/freeform/addon_builder/addon_builder.php
```

(around line 4290) with this:

```
public function get_session_id()
{
    if ( ! isset(ee()->session) || ! is_object(ee()->session))
    {
        $s = 0;
    }
    //EE 2.8+
    else if (version_compare($this->ee_version, '2.8', '>='))
    {
        $s = ee()->session->session_id();
    }
    //EE 2.7.x and below
    else
    {
        $admin_session_type = ee()->config->item('admin_session_type');

        if (
            $admin_session_type == 's' &&
            isset(ee()->session->userdata['session_id'])
        )
        {
            $s = ee()->session->userdata['session_id'];
        }

        else if (
            $admin_session_type == 'cs' &&
            isset(ee()->session->userdata['fingerprint'])
        )
        {
            $s = ee()->session->userdata['fingerprint'];
        }

        else
        {
            $s = 0;
        }
    }

    return $s;
}
//END get_session_id
```

Comment: Fixed my issue on EE 2.5.5.